# ldapsearch for Active Directory search

Tags: search, active-directory, ldap

I have lot of ad groups which start with `ad-grp-<something>-something`.

I want to run the ldapsearch command to pull the members of the group all I need is the member id, not the full name.

```
ldapsearch -xLLL -b "DC=myteam,DC=com" -D user@myteam -h my-host.myteam.com 
           -w Abcd123 "(&(objectClass=group) "(&(memberOf=CN=ad-grp-*,OU=PermissionGroups,OU=Groups,DC=myteam,DC=com))"
```

With this I get the full name of the member but I am looking to get the member id of that user.

Can you help me?

Or share if there is any other easy way?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use wildcards on any attributes that have a `distinguishedName` in the value, like `memberOf`. So you will have to first search for the groups: `(&(objectClass=group)(cn=ad-grp-*))`

If you're sure the membership list of each group is less than 1500, then you can use the `member` attribute from the search. But if some of those groups have more than 1500 members, it gets more complicated to find them all (it only gives you 1500 at a time).

If some of them might be large groups, then you can take the full `distinguishedName` for each of the groups (from the search results) and construct a new query to find the members of each one. Something like this:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(|(memberOf=CN=ad-grp-1,OU=PermissionGroups,OU=Groups,DC=myteam,DC=com)(memberOf=CN=ad-grp-2,OU=PermissionGroups,OU=Groups,DC=myteam,DC=com)))
```

That shows only two groups (`ad-grp-1` and `ad-grp-2`). Add all of them to the query.